# why the test library libunifex in c++ calculate twice?

Tags: c++

I have studied and tried to test the ability of libunifex in these days, but I found it does not work as I expected. Here is an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/zdf9vMrc5):

```
#include <unifex/sync_wait.hpp>
#include <unifex/then.hpp>
#include <unifex/when_all.hpp>
#include <unifex/single_thread_context.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace unifex;

    single_thread_context context;
    sender auto s0 = schedule(context.get_scheduler());
    sender auto s1 = then(s0, [](){
        std::cout << "do complex computation" << std::endl;
    });
    sender auto s21 = then(s1, [](){});
    sender auto s22 = then(s1, [](){});
    sync_wait(when_all(s21, s22));
}
```

In my requirement, I do a complexed computation in s1, so I expect the complexted computation only do once. However, it does the complexed computation twice.
I have two questions:

1. Is my requirement (make s1 compute once) supported by the [paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2300r1.html)? (Sorry, the paper is a little complicated for me.)
2. I found the split function is not implemented yet in libunifex, does it have relation to my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

"Complex computation" have done twice because of you call it twice. The first one is in:

```
 sender auto s21 = then(s1, [](){});
```

another is in:

```
sender auto s22 = then(s1, [](){});
```